# while loop multiplication table python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, nested

Okay so basically what I am trying to accomplish is only using while loops and using them efficiently. Nested while loops are very tricky for me and hard to understand. I am trying to make a 10x10 multiplication table with a header.

So my current code is:

```
firstNumber = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
secondNumber = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))
count = 0
while(count < 1):
    print("{:17} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5}"\
      .format(firstNumber, firstNumber + 1, firstNumber + 2, firstNumber + 3,\
              firstNumber + 4, firstNumber + 5, firstNumber + 6, firstNumber\
              + 7, firstNumber + 8, firstNumber + 9))
    print("{:5} {:}".format(" ", "-"*65))
    count += 1
    counter = 0
    while(counter < 10):
        downSolution = firstNumber * secondNumber
        print("{:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5}"\
              .format(secondNumber, "|", downSolution,\
                  downSolution + secondNumber, downSolution +\
                  (secondNumber * 2), downSolution + (secondNumber * 3),\
                  downSolution + (secondNumber * 4), downSolution + \
                  (secondNumber * 5), downSolution + (secondNumber * 6),\
                  downSolution + (secondNumber * 7), downSolution + \
                  (secondNumber * 8), downSolution + (secondNumber * 9)))
        counter += 1
        secondNumber += 1
```

which outputs:

```
            5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
 5 |        25    30    35    40    45    50    55    60    65    70
 6 |        30    36    42    48    54    60    66    72    78    84
 7 |        35    42    49    56    63    70    77    84    91    98
 8 |        40    48    56    64    72    80    88    96   104   112
 9 |        45    54    63    72    81    90    99   108   117   126
10 |        50    60    70    80    90   100   110   120   130   140
11 |        55    66    77    88    99   110   121   132   143   154
12 |        60    72    84    96   108   120   132   144   156   168
13 |        65    78    91   104   117   130   143   156   169   182
14 |        70    84    98   112   126   140   154   168   182   196
```

Which is basically correct but apparently I didn't do it correctly. So how would I nest the loops more efficiently for the while loops to deal with only one single number at a time instead of ten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem with the code you posted is that your outer `while` loop will actually only run one time. Since you run `while(count < 1)`, and you increment `count` by one after you run the loop once, this loop will exit when its running the second time.

While your answer does print the correct multiplication table, it kind of breaks the spirit of practicing `while` loops by printing 10 numbers with your manually coded results. A smarter way to do this would be to let the program count to 10 for you, instead of listing 10 fields in each row that you manually fill in, like this:

```
firstNumber  = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
secondNumber = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))

# Print twelve spaces in order to format the columns correctly, but don't
# place a newline after the print statement
print(" "*12, end="")

# Loop through all of the column header values in the first row
columnCounter = 0
while columnCounter < 10:
    # Print a single incremented column value, with a space separating each
    print("{:5}".format(firstNumber + columnCounter), end=" ")
    columnCounter = columnCounter + 1

# Add a newline to go to the next row
print("")

# Print the dashes separating the first row from the rest
print("{:5} {:}".format(" ", "-"*65))

# Print the remainder of the rows in the table
rowCounter = 0
while(rowCounter < 10):
    # Print the left-hand side value
    print("{:5} {:5}".format(secondNumber, "|"), end=" ")

    downSolution = firstNumber * secondNumber

    # Loop through the values for all columns for this row
    columnCounter = 0
    while(columnCounter < 10):
        print("{:5}".format(downSolution + secondNumber*columnCounter), end= " ")
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1

    secondNumber = secondNumber + 1
    print("")
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:

```
 row = 1
 row_stop = 10
 while row != row_stop:
    print(row, end = " ") #end = " " adds a spaceafter each print statement
                          #instead of a new line
    row += 1
```

will output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The second loop is the trickier one right?  Once you get to the end of row, its going to be at 11 so it won't keep looping.  If you have two loops though you could do:

```
row = 1
row_stop = 10
col = 1
col_stop = 10
while row != row_stop:
  wile col != col_stop:
    #print your column stuff
  #reset your column counter, 
  #increment your row counter
```

Post this last part and I will help you debug.